# I want to know the coordinates of a finger touch on a touchscreen (subview) to be displayed on a GUI running on the PC (parent view)

Tags: c#, delphi, camera, coordinates

I have tried and tried and it has been 2 weeks (long enough?) but I cannot get this to work, the sub-view screen is being observed by 2 cameras at the top corners (right and left) and the GUI on a parent screen is reading output values from the camera and displaying the x and y coordinates.

I am writing this in C#, could someone just provide an inept explanation of what I would need to do to make this work? Thanks, you guys are the best! Here is the **Delphi code** that does the similar thing.

```
Procedure MouseLeftClick(beam1:integer; beam2:integer);

var

coordXLocal, coordYLocal : single;

coordXScreen, CoordYScreen :single;

  angle1, angle2 : single;
const
  base:single=1100;
begin
  beep;
  angle1:=(beam1/128) * 90;

angle2:=(beam2/128) * 90;

angle2:=90-angle2;

coordXLocal:=(base*tan(degtorad(angle2)))/(tan(degtorad(angle1))+tan(degtorad(angle2)));

coordYLocal:=coordXLocal*tan(degtorad(angle1));
```